# How do I rotate an image by an arbitrary amount?

Tags: image-rotation, dm-script

I have a DigitalMicrograph image which I would like to rotate by a certain amount (not 90 degree). This can be done by the menu item "Process...\Rotate" but I would like to do this by script. I have a script which computes the angle based on a line-ROI found on the image. (see below), but I do not know how I can then rotate the image.

```
Number kPi = 3.14159265359

Image front := GetFrontImage()
ImageDisplay fDisp = front.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
ROI line = fDisp.ImageDisplayGetRoi(0)
if ( line.RoiIsValid() )
{
    if ( line.RoiIsLine() )
    {
        number sx,sy,ex,ey
        line.RoiGetLine(sx,sy,ex,ey)
        number dy = ey - sy
        number dx = ex - sx
        number angle = atan( dy / dx ) * 180/kPi
        if ( dx < 0 ) 
            angle = angle + 180

        Result("\n Rotate image by " + angle + " degree.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice idea for a tool and good coding so far.

The command you are looking for is simply called `Rotate()`. You 've possibly missed it in the help documentation because it is (unfortunately) not listed in the 'image' section. There is a dedicated "reference" section meant to summarize the "simple" script commands of everyday quick-scripting:

[image]

With this command, your script can be modified to the one below. Note that I've also replaced your `kPi` by the command `PI()`. The `Rotate()` command requires the rotation angle to be given in radians. The size of the resulting image will be enlarged and the image is zero-padded.
Also: I've replaced your If - statement with an abbreviated version.

```
Image front := GetFrontImage()
ImageDisplay fDisp = front.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
ROI line = fDisp.ImageDisplayGetRoi(0)
if ( line.RoiIsValid() )
{
    if ( line.RoiIsLine() )
    {
        number sx, sy, ex, ey
        line.RoiGetLine( sx, sy, ex, ey )
        number dy = ey - sy
        number dx = ex - sx
        number angle = atan( dy / dx ) + ( dx < 0 ? Pi() : 0 )
        image out := front.Rotate( angle )
        out.ShowImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very quick. A sub-question: Is there a similar command for 3D images?

Comment: Yes and no. The command Rotate() acts on 3D stacks as well. (Rotating the whole stack in XY-plane), but there is no command for general 3D-rotation. (If you want to rotate in XZ or YZ you can first 'flip' the whole stack and then apply Rotate().)

Comment: Thanks. The xy rotation was all I was looking for now. But out of curiosity: How do I 'flip' a whole stack around 90 degrees so that f.e. the XY plane becomes the visible, screen-parallel plane?

Comment: Use the Slice3() command. You can specify starting point and any (orthogonal) direction as well as sampling. The syntax is Slice3( image, x,y,y, d1,s1,ss1, d2,s2,ss2, d3,s3,ss3) with (x,y,z) the startpoint and the other 3 triplets defining the 3 axes of your output as "dimension, steps, stepsize".